# How I tighten bicycle spokes?

Tags: rear-wheel, spokes

Yes, it's an easy question on the surface, but there are some complications:

1. I lost one of the nipples. So I'm riding without a spoke.
2. One or two of the nipples work themselves loose, but they fall back into place with a bit of coaxing.

EDIT: I think I'll just check if I stripped the nipples or spokes.

Comment: "but they fall back into place with a bit of coaxing." what does this mean?

Comment: It is a bit too complex subject to fit in an answer, but if you search for wheel truing there is already a lot written about it.

Comment: @PaulH They slide around on the spoke. But they don't stick out and punch the tire or something. I hoped that an inflated inner tube would keep them in place.

Comment: There's so much to unpack in that last comment that I highly recommend you take this wheel to a competent shop and let them handle this.

Comment: @ojs Just looked up truing. No, the rim is fine, it's just the nipples are loose.

Comment: @EthanMiller sis you notice anything related to spoke tension there? The nipples are tightened by turning them with spoke wrench, the difficult part is knowing how far to turn. And as you noticed, not stripping anything.

Comment: @ojs I don't follow.

Comment: @EthanMiller Read the instructions. Pay attention to the part where spoke tension is adjusted. This is the tightening part you are looking for. If you have missing spokes or spokes and nipples with stripped threads, replace them before continuing.

Comment: @ojs No, I mean why would you use a wrench for a flat-head screw? But okay — I don't have a special torque wrench but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @EthanMiller just read the instructions. Anyways, the point of the spoke wrench is that it can be used without taking off tire or rim tape and it can handle higher torque than a screwdriver. It's not a special torque wrench. You should be able to buy one under 5€/$/£, maybe up to 10 if you want something fancy.

Comment: @EthanMiller A spoke wrench is designed specifically to interface with the flats on a spoke nipple. The slot on the end of the nipple is not intended for bringing the spoke up to its final tension, and indeed the spoke can protrude all the way through the nipple, making it impossible to use a screw driver.

Comment: Also, I'd second Paul's recommendation to get this checked over by a decent bike shop.

Comment: It should be noted that spoke tension is adjusted by twisting the nipple with a "spoke wrench".  When you do this you should watch the spoke to be sure that it DOESN'T turn (very much) so that the twisting effort is going into screwing the nipple onto the end of the spoke more tightly.  If the spoke insists on turning you need to hold it still with a pair of pliers or such while you twist the spoke wrench.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple.

1. replace the nipple. That involves also replacing the rim strip.
2. buy a new spoke. The lengths are critical, might be more bother than worth.
3. Install new spoke with proper crossing among the existing spokes.
4. Tighten new spoke to mild tension.
5. True the wheel if necessary.

Alternatively, bring it to a trusted bike shop and hand it over. I used to be one of those guys, we much preferred a bare problem than a re-visit to fix your "solution."

Comment: Rim strip (for use with tubes) is normally meant to be reused; I've never needed to replace it in rebuilds even of very old wheels